# AngularJS not recognized in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate AngularJS into my Ruby On Rails application, however when I do so, the AngularJS isn't recognized.

Here are my Javascript files.

/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require_tree ./angular
```

/assets/javascripts/angular/pallets.js

```
var app = angular.module('setPoints', []);
app.controller('pointCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.initials = function() {
        return $scope.origin.charAt(0) + $scope.end_point.charAt(0)
    }
});
```

I also have angular.js and angular-mocks.js downloaded from https://code.angularjs.org/

And here is where I'm trying to call it into the application.

views/pallets/_form.html.erb

```
<div ng-app="setPoints" ng-controller="pointCtrl">
            <td>{{initials()}}<%= id %></td>
            <td><%= select(:pallet, :starting_point, select_options, :ng => {:model => "origin"}) %></td>
            <td><%= select(:pallet, :destination, select_options, :ng => {:model => "end_point"}) %></td>
</div>
```

The output of the page is just {{initials()}}1 instead of what it should be.

When I check the page source the scripts look like this.

```
<script src="/assets/angular.self-649179d58f3f4fbcbbe6a2ce7aad77642c6ff28734d531a57e415bea7d8214f6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular/pallets.self-c14bf66f153614a582c54afa623e187c7b123469c25df99f576e9d130d7b403d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-624ae67626e4a5ceec5f86543694500e04c25f404d2959217eab0ada97ee3895.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error message/problem you notice that tells you Angular is not working?

Comment: The output is just '{{initials()}}1' instead of the function itself.

Comment: Inspect the web page that is being generated. Do you see that Rails has inserted `<script>` tags for Angular.js and for your controller class? Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: I edited the question to include both the output on the page itself and the source. The console has a warning that I didn't see before, 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. '

EDIT: Just fixed that warning by getting rid of the last line shown on the scripts in the question, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The JS files should be in `app/assets/javascripts/` directory.
You're keeping it in wrong place.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the Javascripts portion of the link in the question. The application itself has them in the correct directory.